# Load more RSS posts at bottom of UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have RSS Posts loaded into a UITableView, and the number of posts is determined by this method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (rss.loaded == YES) {
        return [rssItems count]*2;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

How could I load more posts into the tableview after hitting the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger it when the last cell is loaded.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   .
   .
   .
   if (allForecastObjects.count == indexPath.row+1) {
      [self getAndAppendMoreData];
   }
}

-(void)getAndAppendMoreData {

   //this kicks of a preferably asynchronous call for data
   //after new data is added to array/collection reload table view

}

-(void)getAndAppendMoreDataCompleted {

   if (success) {
      [yourTableView reloadData];
   }

}
```

Hope this helps.